# Error while get revel framework with go get

Tags: go, revel

I want to install Revel framework with

> go get github.com/revel/revel

I run it and I got error:

> C:/Users/User/go>go get github.com/revel/revel
>
> github.com revel/revel
>
> src\github.com\revel\revel\server_adapter_go.go:135:79: undefined:
> syscall.SIGUSR2

My GOPATH var is `C:/Users/User/go`

The bin folder was created inside my GOPATH folder. But when I tried to run sample app, it produced similar error

> The Go code src\github.com\revel\revel\server_adapter_go.go does not
> compile: undefined: syscall.SIGUSR2

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us your version of go?

Comment: go1.11 windows/amd64 @yorodm

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be an unresolved issue https://github.com/revel/revel/issues/747

Comment: help to vote up pls @yorodm